# PrimeFaces 7.0 DatePicker throws JS TypeError when showTime is set to true

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using the PrimeFaces datePicker component in my .xhtml file like this

```
<p:datePicker id="src_time"
    value="#{flightDetailController.flight.UTCsource}"
    pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" inline="true" />
```

This flightDetailController has a getter and setter for a Flight object

```
public void setFlight(Flight flight) {
    this.flight = flight;
    doReloadFlight();
}

public void doReloadFlight() {
    this.flight = flightService.loadFlight(flight.getFlightId());
}

public Flight getFlight() 
{
    if (flight == null) {
        flight = new Flight();
    }
    return flight;
}
```

And the Flight object has a getter and setter for a Java.util.Date object

```
public Date getUTCsource() {
    return UTCsource;
}

public void setUTCsource(Date uTCsource) {
    UTCsource = uTCsource;
}
```

If I run this code, the flight (which is previously set) will load fine and the datePicker will display the Date of the object. However, when I add the attribute `showTime="True"` to the datePicker, I get the following JS exception in my console:

`Cannot read property 'split' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at K.<computed>.<computed>.parseTime`

I am using PrimeFaces 7.0, where according to the documentation value should be set to a java.util.Date object, and it simply states to enable timePicker functionality by setting showTime="True" so I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this also happen when using [PrimeFaces 8.0.RC1](https://www.primefaces.org/primefaces-8-0-rc1-released/)? There have been multiple issues fixed on datePicker in relation to pattern and time handling.

Comment: It does work in the 8.0.RC1 - Is the component just essentially not functioning in 7.0 then? Can I workaround this somehow or is my best bet just sticking with 8.0 and hoping it doesn't break anything else?

Comment: Does it work if you add " hh:mm" to the pattern? As there where [multiple issues fixed and refatored](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed+datePicker) on the datepicker past months, I'd guess this is a bug. In order to work around this you should get the [PF 7.0 source](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/tree/7.0) and build a version with *.css and *.js excluded from compression so you can better debug the JavaScript source code.

Comment: Additionally a good idea is to test your app using PF 8.0.RC1 and report eventual issues you observe before the final 8.0.0 is released.

Comment: Adding " hh:mm" to the pattern does not work. According to documentation the pattern is only for the date part, and adding a time pattern to it will introduce unexpected character exceptions. I will probably be going with the 8.0.RC1 version for now then.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to create a converter and for the date to be displayed as a String

```
@Dependent
@FacesConverter(value = "fechaHoraConverter", managed = true)
public class FechaHoraConverter implements Converter<Date>{

    private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a");

    @Override
    public Date getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String fecha) {
        try {
            return sdf.parse(fecha);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Date fecha) {
        return sdf.format(fecha);
    }

}


<p:datePicker id="ven" value="#{tr.tarea.vencimiento}" required="true" showTime="true" appendTo="@(body)" showIcon="true" readonlyInput="true" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" hourFormat="12"
                            converter="fechaHoraConverter"/>
```

[Show pickdate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBTbl.png)